# Is "obtention" a word?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, is-it-a-word

"Obtention" shows up in the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obtention) online dictionary. I've never seen it used, though I can't find any good alternatives. What context would you use it in, and when would it be appropriate/inappropriate? Also, is it a real word that people would recognize?

Comment: It's in the OED.

Comment: What context are you using it in that calls for an alternative?  Sounds like a variation of obtaining, like abstaining / abstention.

Comment: Anything can be a word if you get enough people to say it.

Comment: I wouldn't use it, and the only context where it seems right to me is where it is used as a nominal form of *obtain* in the sense of *subsist*, as in *the situation that then obtained*. If you nominalise that you get *the obtention of that situation* - in that phrase I think *obtention* is better than *obtaining* or *obtainment*, but I still wouldn't use it because the construction itself is too convoluted.

Comment: You answer your own question in the first sentence.

Answer (score 3):

The definition is "the action of attaining something."

The definition for *[acquisition](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/acquisition)* is almost identical:

> The buying or obtaining of assets or objects.

(Lexico, powered by Oxford, def 1.2)

In the example sentence from the definition of *[obtention](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/obtention)*:

> Their protests serve no purpose and will only make their obtention of
>   a diploma almost impossible.

(Lexico, powered by Oxford)

"Acquisition" could also work. But "attainment" would be better.

Comment: Thanks. It's a common mistake here. I really did mean the actual OED in my original comment, which is where I'd found it.

Answer (score 1):

There are zero hits for *obtention* in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/). That suggests it is very rare, and most people would not recognize it. Whether or not readers could ascertain its meaning would depend on the particular readers.

It would probably only be useful in certain narrow, abstract contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Historically, *obtention* may have been problematic for a somewhat surprising reason: it might easily be confused with *obtension*—a noun form not of *obtain* but of *obtend*, which has a very different meaning from "obtain." Here are the entries for *obtend*, *obtension*, and *obtention* that appear in [*The Century Dictionary: An Encyclopedic Lexicon of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hppHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA4068&dq=obtend+obtention&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq6Nqt8orjAhXDFjQIHT6RBYcQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=obtend%20obtention&f=false), volume 3 (1914):

> **obtend**† *v.t.* {< L. *obtendere*, stretch or draw before, < *ob*, before, + *tendere*, stretch : see *tend*.} 1. To oppose; hold out in opposition. [Example:] 'Twas given to you your darling son to shrowd, / To draw the dastard from the fighting crowd, / And for a man *obtend* an empty cloud. —*Dryden*, Aeneid, x. 126. 2. To pretend; allege; plead as an excuse; offer as the reason of anything. [Example:] Thou dost with lies the throne invade, / *Obtending* Heaven for whate'er ills befal. —*Dryden*, Iliad, i. 161.
>
> ...
>
> **obtension**† *n.* {< LL. *obtentio*(*n*-) a covering, veiling, obscurity, < L. *obtendere*, pp. *obtentus*, a covering over: see *obtend*.} The act of obtending. *Johnson*.
>
> **obtention** *n.* {= F. *obtention*, OF *obtention* = Sp. *obtención* = Pg. *obtenção*, < LL. as if *obtentio*(*n*-) < L. *obtinere*, pp. *obtentus*, hold, keep, get, acquire: see *obtain*.} Procurement; obtainment. {Rare.} [Example:] There was no possibility of granting a pension to a foreigner who resided in his own country while that country was at open war with the land whence he aspired at its *obtention*: a word I make for my passing convenience. —*Mme. D'Arblay*, Diary, VII, 140. (*Davies*.)

The dagger symbol that appears in the entries for *obtend* and *obtension* signifies "obsolete." Still, in the seventeenth, eighteenth, and nineteenth centuries, even the ghost of *obtension* lingering on the misty periphery of the language may have helped dissuade English speakers from rushing to embrace *obtention*, especially as *obtending* has very little overlap in meaning with *obtaining*. It is interesting in this regard that the *Century Dictionary* suggests "obtainment" as being the core meaning of *obtention*; whereas the dictionary labels *obtention* "Rare," it attaches no such label to *obtainment*.